# How to detect faces on Android camera frames at minimum 20fps

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection, face-recognition

I am working on an android project that takes camera frames and detect faces. Then I am doing some drawing with OpenGL. Currently, algorithm does face detection on every frame which provides me approximately 10fps for 320x240 image. I would like to increase fps amount to minimum 20 fps. How can I increase the speed or which algortihm can provide me that fps?

What I have tried to achieve that so far;

-Downscaled the image x4 times from 1280x960 to 320x240

-Skipped face detection on one of every two frames.

Comment: Maybe after detecting a face you can track it instead of detecting it again. Tracking should be faster and allows you run the detection after masking out the area of the image where you are tracking.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger tracking+detection takes approximately same amount of time. Not making much difference.

Comment: Are you sure that the low fps is mostly due to the detection algorithm? Maybe the OpenGL drawing itself is causing the low FPS? Have you timed how long it takes for the detection algorithm to run versus how long it takes to draw a single frame in OpenGL?

Comment: @brohan322 yes, detection takes most of the time, opengl finishes in a few miliseconds.